# React Leaflet : ugly Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet, leaf

I've set an leaflet map component that iterate through users fetched from db that contains, for each of them, coordinates.
Devtool throw me:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Not the first time I got this warning and I usually find easily how to fix it but this time I can't find a solution.

All is working fine but this warning keeps triggering me

Console Warning:
[image: Console Warning]

I've tried to put the key as Marker component identifier, Popup component identifier, both of them.

I've seen a post that recommend to put the key as Fragment identifier for each element of my map function. I tried in a div component (seems equal to Fragment to me?) still not working.

```
<MapContainer  id={!isMobile ? "browser-leaflet" : "mobile-leaflet"} center={POSITION} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
    <TileLayer
    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?lang=fr"
    />
    {contacts.map(contact => (
        <div key={contact.email}> <-- last try here
            <Marker //also tried here// position={[contact.lat, contact.lon]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: contact.is_client ? markerIconClient : markerIconProspect, iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})}>
                <Popup //also tried here// offset={[0, -15]}>
                    <p style={{marginBottom: "1vh", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "1.5em"}}>
                        {contact.raison_sociale}
                    </p>
                    <Button variant="sub" className="mx-auto" style={{border: "teal", borderRadius: "15px", fontSize: "1em", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                        <a 
                        href={"https://www.waze.com/fr/live-map/directions?navigate=yes&to=ll." + contact.lat + "%2C" + contact.lon}
                        style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black", backgroundColor: "#D0FCB3"}}
                        >
                            Allez-y
                        </a>
                    </Button>
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </div>
    ))}
    <SetMap />
</MapContainer>
```

Error seems to be located @Geolocalisation.jsx (my whole page compo) line:102 which is where I set style and navbar based on client device.

```
return ( <--- here l:102
        <>
            {!isMobile ? (
                [
                    <BrowserSidenav />, 
                    <style>
                        {browserLeafletContainer}
                    </style>
                ]
            ) : (
                <style>
                    {mobileLeafletContainer}
                </style>
            )}
```

Does someone knows how to fix it?
(P.S: sorry for bad English, not native and not using online translator)

Whole return from my component Geolocalisation.jsx : (funcs are just a users fetch, a useEffect that delete users with no lat/lon.

```
return (
        <>
            {!isMobile ? (
                [
                    <BrowserSidenav />, 
                    <style>
                        {browserLeafletContainer}
                    </style>
                ]
            ) : (
                <style>
                    {mobileLeafletContainer}
                </style>
            )}

            <MapContainer  id={!isMobile ? "browser-leaflet" : "mobile-leaflet"} center={POSITION} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?lang=fr"
                />
                {contacts.map(contact => (
                    <div key={contact.email}>
                        <Marker position={[contact.lat, contact.lon]} icon={new Icon({iconUrl: contact.is_client ? markerIconClient : markerIconProspect, iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41]})}>
                            <Popup offset={[0, -15]}>
                                <p style={{marginBottom: "1vh", textAlign: "center", fontSize: "1.5em"}}>
                                    {contact.raison_sociale}
                                </p>
                                <Button variant="sub" className="mx-auto" style={{border: "teal", borderRadius: "15px", fontSize: "1em", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                                    <a 
                                    href={"https://www.waze.com/fr/live-map/directions?navigate=yes&to=ll." + contact.lat + "%2C" + contact.lon}
                                    style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "black", backgroundColor: "#D0FCB3"}}
                                    >
                                        Allez-y
                                    </a>
                                </Button>
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    </div>
                ))}
                <SetMap />
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: `.map` provides an index as well, ex: `contacts.map((contact,index) => (`, that index will always be unique, try it

Comment: I know but I also manage contacts in another component of my app with C U D operations. Someone told me to use index only when my list's objects are static (it's multi account app so if someone edit list of contacts while i'm on my map component it risks any conflict?) 

I use email wich is a unique value in db ;/ 

edit: whole map component is only fetched once no auto refresh so index should work because it reorder indexes at every web browser refresh. I've tried and it's not fixing my pb :s


https://imgur.com/kWgOi7b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there are same emails in data 'contacts'. Make sure each key for div is unique.

Comment: email is unique value in db

Comment: check concats in console when the warning shows. it helps locate the problem. If it's unique, you can delete every  suspicious part in your codes one by one to see whether the warning disappear or not.

Comment: https://imgur.com/v07zqy7 ? what concats? i don't concat emails, i use db row value as key, no edit (i'm new to react and js so i don't really know how to handle correctly errors, it's often hard for me to trigger where is the real pb)

Comment: sry,it's a typo. 'contacts.map(contact => (
                    <div key={contact.email}> ...' it's in your code,  the data 'contacts', just use 'console.log(contacts)' to check it in browser console, check if the email field value is unique.

Comment: done in the pic I gave you in upper response --> imgur.com/v07zqy7  :/ they are all differents

Comment: then `[
                    <BrowserSidenav />, 
                    <style>
                        {browserLeafletContainer}
                    </style>
                ]` may be the problem, try `<React.Fragment><BrowserSidenav /> 
                    <style>
                        {browserLeafletContainer}
                    </style></React.Fragment>`

Comment: Ok fine it fixed it but know fragment is breaking my css x)  

Thanks to you, :D

Comment: ok css break was due to "," after SideBar  when it was displayed as array instead of fragment. 

"," character is poping inline-block elem of fragment. I deleted it and it's now clean of errors and css break. u rlly rock thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that undefined is also a key-value.

If you have unique emails in your DB, but not required, then there might be several people without email.

I normally go for the _id/id or concider using several fields to build a key.
You could also do key={contact.email ?? contact.phone} Or another attribute if email is undefined...